# How to create a sequence of modal/push segues between few view controllers to keep all the push/modal views on the same stack? (using nibs)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to create push and modal segues the right way, and from what I understand is to embed my root view controller in a navigation controller in my app delegate...So when I want to create segues they all will be modal/pushed to the same stack..is that right?

I'm really trying to understand this since i'm having some issues doing it correctly.

I want to be able to perform :

**FirstViewController** > click on a button (modal segue) > **SecondViewController** > click on a button (push) > **ThirdViewController**

And from the ThirdViewController I will click on cancel take the ThirdViewController of the stack and get to the SecondViewController click cancel take SecondViewController of the stack and get to the FirstViewController which is my rootviewcontroller and it will be the only view controller in the viewstack...

isn't it how it's suppose to work? please correct me if I'm wrong.

This is how I did it so far: (I know how to dismiss view controllers so I did not add this code)

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "FirstViewController"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstViewController *firstViewController;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize firstViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];


    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: firstViewController];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now in the second ViewController I'm trying to think how to get to the rood navigation controller so I can add to it another screen instead of creating another navigation controller in SecondViewController.

Comment: did you see my answers? does it work for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *first* want to use a `modal` segue and then a `push` segue, you need to embed the modal view controller into an instance of `UINavigationController`.

For your setup, it'll look like this:

```
- (IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender {
       SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil]; // can be  [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil] as well...
}
```

Then you can implement e.g. `goToThird` in `SecondViewController` like so:

```
- (IBAction)goToThird {
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

[self.navigationController presentViewController: secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

You should push view controllers onto the navigation controller stack

[self.navigationController pushViewController: secondViewController animated:YES];

Every view controller has a navigation controller property, so you can access the navigation controller from any view controller on the stack.